# plt.scatter; SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I've seen this questions asked quite a few times but I none of the solutions were associated with the `plt.scatter` function.

Here is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(df.pickup_longitude,df.pickup_latitude, 
            c = df.pickup_cluster, cmap = 'autumn','.', alpha = 0.4, markersize = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-42-6be5f7d17c02>", line 3
    c = df.pickup_cluster, cmap = 'autumn','.', alpha = 0.4, markersize = 0.5)
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Any recommendations would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of to the `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` is always the same: You have some argument after a keyword argument, e.g.

```
function(1,2, arg=3, arg=4, 5, arg=6)
```

The number `5` here is an argument which sits after you started with keyword arguments.

```
cmap = 'autumn','.', alpha = 0.4,
                 |
               here
```

This `'.'` needs a keyword as well, which would be `marker`.

```
plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, marker='.', alpha = 0.4, markersize = 0.5)
```

You may be interested in reading the [chapter on keyword args](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) in the python doc.

Comment: Interesting, will definitely take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't specify positional (not named) arguments after keyword arguments:

```
plt.scatter(df.pickup_longitude,df.pickup_latitude, 
            c = df.pickup_cluster, cmap = 'autumn', 
            marker='.', alpha = 0.4, markersize = 0.5)
# NOTE:     ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have `'.'` after some keyword parameters. Use keyword parameter for that one too. That should solve the problem.